# ¿Cómo arreglo mi slide usando carousel?

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, css3

Estoy trabajando con html, css y js creando una página personalizada. Resulta que el slide principal dejo de funcionar, pero lo extraño es que no muestra el error al inspeccionar elemento en js, los bullets tampoco funcionan si hago click en uno de ellos.

Este es el código del carousel:

```html
<div class="profundo carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" id="bs-carousel">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                    <img class="logo" src="img/logo-blanco-home.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 text-right">
                    <img class="siguiente" src="img/siguiente.png" alt="Aproblemados">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Overlay -->
        <div class="overlay"></div>

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item slides active">
                <div class="slide-1"></div>
                <div class="hero">
                    <hgroup>
                        <h1>Que no sea DEMASIADO TARDE 1</h1>
                        <h3>Te asesoramos con tus problemas legales</h3>
                    </hgroup>
                    <div class="btn-slide text-center">
                        <a href="#contacto" class="btn btn-hero btn-lg">Contáctanos</a><br>
                        <img src="img/escritorio/mouse.png" alt="Aproblemados">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item slides">
                <div class="slide-2"></div>
                <div class="hero">
                    <hgroup>
                        <h1>Que no sea DEMASIADO TARDE 2</h1>
                        <h3>Te asesoramos con tus problemas legales</h3>
                    </hgroup>
                    <div class="btn-slide text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Contáctanos</button><br>
                        <img src="img/escritorio/mouse.png" alt="Aproblemados">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item slides">
                <div class="slide-3"></div>
                <div class="hero">
                    <hgroup>
                        <h1>Que no sea DEMASIADO TARDE 3</h1>
                        <h3>Te asesoramos con tus problemas legales</h3>
                    </hgroup>
                    <div class="btn-slide text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Contáctanos</button><br>
                        <img src="img/escritorio/mouse.png" alt="Aproblemados">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Les comparto la url para que puedan ver de lo que les hablo:

https://marketadvisor.cl/aproblemados/

La pregunta es, que me falta para que el slide funcione ?

Answer (score 1):

Examinando un poco tu código desde la terminal. Me he dado cuenta que no tienes los archivos para tu carousel, o quizá yo no lo hallé, asegurate de estar incluyendo los archivos `css` y `js` del carousel que estás intentando hacer funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Estás usando mal la clase `carousel-item`, pues has puesto `item` a secas en su lugar.

En bootstrap 4 se usa `carousel-item`. En bootstrap 3 se usa `item`, y tu estás usando la versión 4.6 en tu web.

Por lo tanto, busca **item** y modificalo por **carousel-item** y empezará a funcionarte bien.

Aquí te dejo un snippet funcionando con tu código y ese cambio que acabo de decir:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="profundo carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" id="bs-carousel">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                    <img class="logo" src="img/logo-blanco-home.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 text-right">
                    <img class="siguiente" src="img/siguiente.png" alt="Aproblemados">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Overlay -->
        <div class="overlay"></div>

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item slides active">
                <div class="slide-1"></div>
                <div class="hero">
                    <hgroup>
                        <h1>Que no sea DEMASIADO TARDE 1</h1>
                        <h3>Te asesoramos con tus problemas legales</h3>
                    </hgroup>
                    <div class="btn-slide text-center">
                        <a href="#contacto" class="btn btn-hero btn-lg">Contáctanos</a><br>
                        <img src="img/escritorio/mouse.png" alt="Aproblemados">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item slides">
                <div class="slide-2"></div>
                <div class="hero">
                    <hgroup>
                        <h1>Que no sea DEMASIADO TARDE 2</h1>
                        <h3>Te asesoramos con tus problemas legales</h3>
                    </hgroup>
                    <div class="btn-slide text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Contáctanos</button><br>
                        <img src="img/escritorio/mouse.png" alt="Aproblemados">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item slides">
                <div class="slide-3"></div>
                <div class="hero">
                    <hgroup>
                        <h1>Que no sea DEMASIADO TARDE 3</h1>
                        <h3>Te asesoramos con tus problemas legales</h3>
                    </hgroup>
                    <div class="btn-slide text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Contáctanos</button><br>
                        <img src="img/escritorio/mouse.png" alt="Aproblemados">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando bootstrap 4, cambia estas clases de estilo "item slides" por **carousel-item** y asegúrate de agregar las referencias.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://marketadvisor.cl/aproblemados/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" id="bs-carousel">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                    <img class="logo" src="img/logo-blanco-home.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 text-right">
                    <img class="siguiente" src="img/siguiente.png" alt="Aproblemados">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Overlay -->
        <div class="overlay"></div>

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="slide-1"></div>
                <div class="hero">
                    <hgroup>
                        <h1>Que no sea DEMASIADO TARDE 1</h1>
                        <h3>Te asesoramos con tus problemas legales</h3>
                    </hgroup>
                    <div class="btn-slide text-center">
                        <a href="#contacto" class="btn btn-hero btn-lg">Contáctanos</a><br>
                        <img src="https://marketadvisor.cl/aproblemados/img/escritorio/persona-natural.png" alt="Aproblemados">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="slide-2"></div>
                <div class="hero">
                    <hgroup>
                        <h1>Que no sea DEMASIADO TARDE 2</h1>
                        <h3>Te asesoramos con tus problemas legales</h3>
                    </hgroup>
                    <div class="btn-slide text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Contáctanos</button><br>
                        <img src="https://html.com/wp-content/uploads/flamingo.webp" alt="Aproblemados">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="slide-3"></div>
                <div class="hero">
                    <hgroup>
                        <h1>Que no sea DEMASIADO TARDE 3</h1>
                        <h3>Te asesoramos con tus problemas legales</h3>
                    </hgroup>
                    <div class="btn-slide text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Contáctanos</button><br>
                        <img src="https://marketadvisor.cl/aproblemados/img/escritorio/servicio-empresa.png" alt="Aproblemados">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```